# Notifications (wakeup) on Samsung S10 with Android 10 not working as expected

Tags: android, android-notifications, samsung-mobile, android-10.0

In my app it is important to display a notification at a certain point in time (as alarm for Accident detection if the user does not move anymore).

This alarm is working on all Android versions < 10 and is also working with the most Phones with android 10. One of the exceptions seams to be the Samsung S10 (Plus). With this Phone all notifications are for 1-2 minutes delayed if the Phone is in Sleep-Mode (Display is black)!

Here some code snippets to show the Problem.

First we tried to do it with an JobIntentService:

```
public class MyNotificationService extends JobIntentService {

    ....

    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {

        NotificationType notificationType = NotificationType.valueOf(intent.getExtras().getInt(INTENT_EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_TYPE));
        boolean alarmingNotification = intent.getBooleanExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_ALARM, false);

        NotificationStorage notificationStorage = NotificationStorage.getInstance(context);
        notificationStorage.setPendingNotificationType(notificationType);

        intent.putExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_ALARM_NOTIFICATION, alarmingNotification);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        intent.setClass(context, PopupOnLockScreenActivity.class);

        startActivity(notificationStarterIntent)
    }

    ...

}
```

Result: Popup does not open immediately as expected (1-2 minutes delayed)

Then i tried as workaround with Notification with a NotificationChannel (IMPORTANCE_HIGH) and NotificationCompat.Builder (PRIORITY_MAX):

```
public class MyNotificationService extends JobIntentService {

    ....

    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {

        NotificationType notificationType = NotificationType.valueOf(intent.getExtras().getInt(INTENT_EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_TYPE));
        boolean alarmingNotification = intent.getBooleanExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_ALARM, false);

        NotificationStorage notificationStorage = NotificationStorage.getInstance(context);
        notificationStorage.setPendingNotificationType(notificationType);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            Log.d(TAG, "showPopupOnLockScreen XXX");


            String channelName = getResources().getString(R.string.safety_notification_channel_name);
            //String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
            String description = "XXXXX";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            android.app.NotificationChannel channel = new android.app.NotificationChannel(UepaaNetAndroidConstants.ANDROID_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
            // or other notification behaviors after this
            android.app.NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(android.app.NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channel.getId())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_symptom_small)
                    .setContentTitle("My notification")
                    .setContentText("Hello World!")
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);

            notificationManager.notify(123, builder.build());

        }

    }

    ...

}
```

Result: Notification will be not showed immediately as expected (1-2 minutes delayed)

**Wake-Up does not work on Samsung S10**

I also tried to put the app in the lists to prevent the app from Battery-Manager and Sleep-Modes. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=npGw_r-v25k) But the problem still exists!

Can somebody help me? Our app is useless without notifications.

To reproduce this problem I pushed a project on github: https://github.com/gatschet/androidAlarmTest.git